# Does exist $f: V \otimes V \to V$ such that $(f(x,y),z) = (x,f(y,z))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $V$ is complex vector space with nondegenerate scalar product. Does $f\colon V \otimes V \to V$, such that $(f(a \otimes b),c) = (a,f(b \otimes c))$ and $f \neq 0$, exist? It is obvious that such function doesn't exist when $\operatorname{dim} V = 1$, but what about other dimensions?

It is also interesting for me what will be in case when base field is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Given the notation $f(a,b)$ I have to ask: Do you really mean $V\otimes V$ or $V\times V$?

Comment: I mean $V \otimes V$.

Comment: I edited start post already. But for me symbols "$\otimes$" and "$,$" is more or less interchangeable ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing  that it's supposed to be clear from  the context that you're actually asking about the existence  of a *linear* $f$ satisfying that identity. In any case, if you add the condition that  $f$ be linear then there is no such map: $(f(x\otimes  y),z)$ is linear in $y$, while $(x,f(y\otimes z))$ is conjugate-linear in $y$.

Comment: Smart! Can you say something about case when base field is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems like killing form of any semisimple lie algebra and $f$ as lie bracket is fits.